# Show current culture decimal separator in xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I want to just show what is set as decimal separator, so either "." or ",".

Neither of these work

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat}, Path=NumberDecimalSeparator}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses for the static property in the Path.

For details, see [PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#propertypath-for-objects-in-data-binding).

```
xmlns:g="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"

<TextBlock Text="{Binding
    Path=(g:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}"/>
```

Or set the Source of the Binding via `x:Static`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding
    Source={x:Static g:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture},
    Path=NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`{x:Static }` works only with `static` properties or fields

CurrentCulture is a static member of CultureInfo, but NumberFormat is an instance member

so the correct use will be:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static g:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}, Path=NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator}"/>
```

where `g` is a namespace definition which contains CurrentCulture class andshould be added on top level (`xmlns:g="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"`)

Comment: Or a composite path, as shown in the other answer.